# how to set a background image for S40 Nokia SDK in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, nokia, midp, series-40

I'm developing an application to work on S40 platform for Nokia devices using Netbeans IDE, I'm working on a visual MIDLET (MIDP 2.1) and I am trying to set a background image for the forms in my application. I can insert an imageItem but it doesn't overlap just like any other item (string item, etc.) so I can't get it to be fixed in the background where all the components will be in front of it like layers.

Is there any way possible to have a background for my Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form components are meant to have the platform's native look and therefore do not support setting a background. You can use Canvas to implement your own custom components. Or you can use a UI library such as [lwuit](http://lwuit.java.net/) for implementing your application's UI.